# Recharts axis domain isn't working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm building a stock visualization app and the Y axis domain for my recharts component isn't working correctly when I select certain stocks. As you can see, when I choose AAPL it works completely fine [AAPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTMGx.png), but when I select AMCR the domain appears to be flipped [AMCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffreq.png).
Here is my code for the chart itself: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgWda.png)

So at first I thought dataMin and dataMax were causing the issue so I set up a useEffect that would set the max and min in state, but I faced the same issue. [useEffect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSzeH.png)

Comment: Do both data have the same format? You could add some console logs and see if they have the same format.